# Accessing methods and attributes from another class without instantiating it

Tags: java

Say I have the following code:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.getB() + " and count " + b.count);
    }
}

class B {
    private int b = 15;
    int count = 0;

    B() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
15 and count 1
```

Which, depending on the use, is ok.

However, `count` is the total amount of objects of type B, and it is added 1 every time a `new B();` comes up. In the code, the third line (where there is a `new B();`), is not supposed to do that. I simply want a reference to the class B, in order to access its attributes and methods.

Is there a way to access methods and attributes without instantiating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, count is the total amount of objects of type B, and it is added 1 every time a new B(); comes up.

wrong. `count` is an instance variable of `B` class, so each time you create an instance of `B`, a new `count` variable is initialized to 0 and incremented to 1 in the `B` constructor.

In order to count all the instances of `B`, make `count` a static variable. This way it won't belong to any instance of `B`, and you can access it with `B.getCount()` (which should also be static).

```
class B {
    private int b = 15;
    private static int count = 0;

    B() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but you missed on the `getB()`. I can't make it static, because I want my b objects to be able to modify its value.

Comment: @LuisEduardo `getB()` can remain as is. I ignored it in my answer since it's not relevant to the count variable implementation.

Comment: Oh, ok. Hadn't realized it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to add the keyword static before it. e.g.

```
class B {
    private int b = 15;
    static int count = 0;

    B() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

this will make this variable shared between all versions of this class rather than be a value on the object itself.

When accessing a static value you should really do it in a slightly different way e.g

B.count (off the class not an instantiated object, but it will work

Comment: all instances, ipv all versions. it'll also be available if there aren't any instances yet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way of accessing certain attributes or behaviors without instantiating classes, which is known as the static keyword. This means, fields and methods marked as static are not dependent on the instances of the class and is available without creating objects.

According to the Oracle Java Documentation, Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

For your purpose (counting instances of class B) I would do something like this:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
        System.out.println(B.count);
        new B();
        System.out.println(B.count);
        new B();
        System.out.println(B.count);
    }
}
class B {
    private int b = 15;
    static int count = 0;
    B() {
        count++;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```