# Simple explanation of fields in Java

Tags: java, static, field

Shouldn't the last print statement output "Vince"? I'd like to know why it didn't and the concept behind it.

See code below:

```
public class Example
{
   static String name;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Example.name = "Vince";
        System.out.println(Example.name) // will print "Vince"

        name = "Tony";
        System.out.println(name); // will still print "Tony"

        System.out.println(Example.name); // will print "Tony"
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. And you can see that it shouldn't, because it doesn't.

Comment: What do you think `name` refers to, if not `Example.name`?

Comment: Both, name and Example.name are referencing the same variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Attempt 2 at answering this question.

`name` is a `static` field. `static` means that this field/attribute is shared amongst all objects of the same type. This means that if I were to make an instance of `Example`, called it `Nancy`, and then I did `Nancy.name = "Drew"`, it would mean that `System.out.println(name)` would now equal `"Drew"` since static fields are shared across all objects of the same type.

Point is, by having the field be `static`, it was guaranteed to change to whatever value that `Example.name` or `this.name` changed it to, depending on which one was more recent.

link for `this` keyword - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

A nice example of this playing out, but a bit differently - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035964/10118965

Comment: "nameless instance of Example"? Never heard that term in Java... `name` is a class field, not an instance field; there is no "nameless" nor "named" instance in Java; maybe a named variable referencing an instance...

Comment: OP's code doesn't create an instance of `Example`; it's only using a _static_ method (`main`) and a variable (`name`) and these are connected to the `Class` object associated with said class, not to an instance of the class.

Comment: As commented, you need to fix that first sentence as it is presently nonsensical. I got where you were headed, but “instance” is exactly the wrong term to be using there.

Comment: Thank you all. How is this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no other symbols called `name` in scope (e.g. no local variables), so `name` refers to the same thing as `Example.name`.

If the code said, for example:

```
String name; // a local variable with the same name
name = "Tony";
System.out.println(name); // will still print "Tony"

System.out.println(Example.name);
```

then the last line *would* print `Vince`, because then you are assigning `Tony` to the local variable.